# Find the limit of the greatest integer function such that

Tags: calculus

[image]

Can someone help me with these limits?
At (a) I found the onesided limits and the right one was 0 and the left one was -infinite. I don't if i am correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct for part $(a)$. Just add that the limit does not exist. For part $(b)$, it will be useful to use the inequalities $1/x - 1 < [[1/x]] \le 1/x$ for $x \neq 0$. Multiplying the inequality by $x$, we get $1 - x < x[[1/x]] \le 1$ for $x > 0$ and $1 \le x[[1/x]] < 1 - x$ for $x < 0$. Since $1 - x \to 1$ as $x \to 0$, the squeeze theorem gives $\lim_{x\to 0^+} x[[1/x]] = \lim_{x\to 0^+} x[[1/x]] = 1$. Thus $\lim_{x\to 0} x[[1/x]] = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are.
Note that around zero greatest integer function acts like 
$$f(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            -1 & \quad x < 0 \\
            0 & \quad x \geq 0
        \end{array}
    \right.$$
So considering $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ from left we have $\lim\frac{-1}{0^-}=\infty$.
Also from right we have $\lim\frac{0}{0^+}=0$

I think that you messed floor and ceiling functions.

Comment: is the limit zero from the right?